# Generate Crystal Report Dynamically reading Store Procedure

Tags: c#, dynamic, webforms, crystal-reports

I am developing a web form application. Here a Create a table named ReportConfig which contains ReportId, ReportCode, ReportName and Query column. An User will put there Store Procedure or select statement in the Query column.
Then, I made another Page named ReportDownload where an user will download a report based on the input he/she gave on the ReportConfig--> Query

Is it possible to create Crystal Report from every Store Procedure or Select statement from query column ?

Here is my ReportConfig page.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ReportManager
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadRecord();
            }
            
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ANIK-IT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ReportManager;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=oLdViCtOrY2008");
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Insert into ReportConfig values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextArea1.InnerText + "')", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Inserted');", true);
            LoadRecord();
        }
      
        void LoadRecord()
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from ReportConfig", con);
            SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            d.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Update ReportConfig Set ReportName = '" + TextBox2.Text + "', Query = '" + TextArea1.InnerText + "' Where ReportCode=  '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Updated');", true);
            LoadRecord();
        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Delete ReportConfig Where ReportCode = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' ", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Successfully Deleted');", true);
            LoadRecord();
        }

        protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from ReportConfig Where ReportCode = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            d.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from ReportConfig Where ReportCode = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader r = comm.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                TextBox2.Text = r.GetValue(2).ToString();
                TextArea1.InnerText = r.GetValue(3).ToString();
            }
            con.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ReportDownload page

```
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ReportManager
{
    public partial class ReportDownload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ANIK-IT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ReportManager;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=oLdViCtOrY2008");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string com = "Select * from ReportConfig";
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adpt.Fill(dt);
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ReportName";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ReportId";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }

        }
        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string chk = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
                string qur = String.Format("Select Query from ReportConfig Where ReportName ='" + chk + "'");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qur, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);

                string dsa = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(dsa, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                sda1.Fill(ds1);

                ReportDocument crp = new ReportDocument();
                crp.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportViewer.rpt"));
                crp.SetDataSource(ds1.Tables["table"]);

                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crp;

                crp.ExportToHttpResponse(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false, "Report Config");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(),"err_msg",
                "alert('Invalid Store Procedure!)');",true);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

also you can see what i do by downloading the project here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GsZSGFmHoINwyuorx3n-o0sH3U8cL2rS/view?usp=sharing